# Compare value in all cells in a column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to use conditional formatting to make all the values in one column that are the same turn red.  I used `arrayformula`, but I can only get it to do that for the first value in the column.

I tried this in the custom formula and applied it to all the cells in the column: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(F1:F10=F:F,1,0))`

Also I'm no expert here, trying to learn as I go.

So if the column has these values (each in their own cell):

```
A
A
B
D
B
N
G
```

I would want the A's and B's to turn red.

Answer (score 2):

Please select ColumnF and apply a Custom formula is of:

```
=countif(F:F,F1)>1
```

Select your format.

[COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480)

For your locale you might need `;` rather than `,`.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: @MKN Could you please mark as the answer? Thanks! :)